# Django wagtail login required not working

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm working on wagtailcms.I just want to display a page only if the user is logged in. I have tried LoginRequiredMixin,@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch') but nothing works.Please help

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
class LessonListPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
""" Lists all the lessons on one page """

    template = "lesson/lesson_list_page.html"

    custom_title = models.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context"""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["posts"] = LessonDetailPage.objects.live(
        ).public().order_by('-first_published_at')[:10]
        #Change 'public' to adjust which posts are displayed
        context["postcategories"] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: At what line do you want to check if the user is logged in?

Comment: I  want to display the lesson_list_page only if user is logged in.Otherwise it will redirect to login page.This is the class that generates the page

Answer (score 3):

On Wagtail page models, [the `serve` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) is the equivalent of a view function, so overriding that method and adding a `method_decorator` ought to work.

However, Wagtail already has this functionality built in: [the privacy controls](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html) provided when you create a page through the admin allow you to set a page as being accessible to logged-in users only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class LessonListPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
""" Lists all the lessons on one page """

    template = "lesson/lesson_list_page.html"

    custom_title = models.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context"""
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
           context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
           context["posts"] = LessonDetailPage.objects.live(
    ).public().order_by('-first_published_at')[:10]
           #Change 'public' to adjust which posts are displayed
           context["postcategories"] = Category.objects.all()
           return context
        else:
           return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - the `get_context` method is used to define the variables to be made available on the page template, and is expected to return a dict of variables. Returning a response object (as in `redirect('/')`) will either fail or be ignored.